# WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies - can't find the root cause

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi

I cannot inject a Logger to a CDI bean. I tried solutions from answers to other similar questions but none have helped. I will really appreciate if you can help me to find what's going on here.

I am using Glassfish 4.0.

**Error message from Eclipse when trying to deploy application:**

```
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Logger] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject protected learning.javaee.guestbook.UnregisteredUserPost.log]. Please see server.log for more details.
```

**CDI bean containing injection point:**

```
package learning.javaee.guestbook;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class UnregisteredUserPost extends AbstractPost {
    private String name;
    private OffsetDateTime dateTime;

    @Inject
    protected Logger log;

    public UnregisteredUserPost() {}

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public OffsetDateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }
    public void setDateTime(OffsetDateTime dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }
    public void save() {
        log.info("TEST");
    }
}
```

**Logger producer:**

```
package learning.javaee.guestbook;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

public class LoggerProducer {
    @Produces
    public Logger produceLogger(InjectionPoint ip) {
        return Logger.getLogger(ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
    }
}
```

**guestbook.xhtml** - calls CDI bean's method `save()` which is using the Logger instance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
  <h:head>
    <title>#{msg.page_title}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"/>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="#{msg.your_name}&#160;"/>
        <h:inputText value="#{unregisteredUserPost.name}"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <h:outputText value="#{msg.your_msg}"/>
        <br/>
        <h:inputTextarea 
            rows="5" cols="100" value="#{unregisteredUserPost.content}"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <h:commandButton 
            value="#{msg.submit}" action="#{unregisteredUserPost.save()}"/>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

**WebContent\WEB-INF\beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes making the producer class @Dependent scoped make it work. But i'm not sure. And in your case, you have "bean-discovery-mode=all" so it doesn't make any differents.

But in your case, you have a mistake in your imports.

Your producer produces a "import org.**jboss.logging**.Logger;" and the injected field is `java.util.logging`.Logger . So you don't have an appropiated producer for de type class you wanted to inject.

Comment: You are right! It solves the problem! Thank you for noticing this mistake.